# How can i view the AT Commands / Communication sent and received from an iPhone's Modem?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I'm looking to view the communication that is transmitted between the network and the modem in an iPhone. Is there any way that I can do this? To be clear I'm not looking for the Get / Post request etc but the actual commands that the modem its self is sending and receiving. I'm using a jailbroken iPhone X.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

First, iPhone doesn't use AT commands to communicate with the baseband (that's a proper term for it). It used to but it was a long time ago and stopped once Apple switched to Qualcomm basebands.

Second, if we're talking about Qualcomm based iPhone X, special protocol is used - QMI. It's a binary protocol made by Qualcomm to communicate with their basebands. On the iPhone the communication is done over the USB bus. So to iOS the baseband is presented as a regular USB device and works like a kind of client (iOS) - server (baseband) communication. All the communication that's happening between the baseband and the actual cellular network is completely hidden from the iOS. QMI is a very high level interface to the baseband where you're dealing with actual calls and messages and not with layers and layers of cellular network protocols. That's all hidden and abstracted away. From what I remember, no debug interfaces are present on the iPhone where you could see what's happening on the network (unlike some Android devices).

I guess Intel basebands, which can also be found in iPhone X, work similarly abstracting and hiding all the ugly details. But I don't know for sure, never reversed Intel based iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small project, a couple of years ago, the main goal was to send/receive APDU commands directly to a SIM card, to communicate with the Java applet installed on the card, it was just a PoC.

I've managed to achieve it, on a jailbroken iPhone 6 with a Qualcomm baseband, running, at that time, iOS 9.0, by wrapping APDUs into QMI protocol and communicating with baseband using IOKit.

But if you need to just sniff the traffic, it's a bit easier, I did it by hooking a couple of callbacks from `libBasebandUSB.dylib` (which `CommCenter` is using) in particular `usb::interface::control::queueControlReadCompletion_sync` and `usb::interface::control::queueControlWriteCompletion_sync`. That way you can see all the callbacks from all the services running on the baseband itself. But again that was back on iOS 9 and with a Qualcomm baseband and might be obsolete by now. Also, I have no idea if Intel basebands support QMI.

I also did a talk about this, [the slides](https://github.com/danylokos/reverse-baseband-slides/blob/master/reverse_baseband.md) might be helpful for you. Also [here is](https://github.com/danylokos/InterCC) a simple `CydiaSubstrate` hook I did, with all the hooked functions I tested.

The results looked like this. Request to change the PIN-code.
[image]